# Using multiple column names in where with RoR and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to produce the following sql using active record.

```
WHERE (column_name1, column_name1) IN (SELECT ....)
```

I don't know how to do this is active record.

I've tried these so far

```
where('column_name1, column_name2' => {})
where([:column_name1, :column_name2] => {})
```

This is the full query I'd like to create

```
SELECT a, Count(1) 
            FROM   table 
            WHERE  ( a, b ) IN (SELECT a, 
                                    Max(b) 
                                    FROM   table 
                                    GROUP  BY a) 
            GROUP  BY a 
            HAVING Count(1) > 1)
```

I've already written a scope for the subquery

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you write out the whole statement you'd like to create

Comment: Edited original answer to include the full statement

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE (column_name1, column_name1) IN (SELECT ....)` is not a valid construct in sql; so it can't be done in active record either.

The valid way of accomplishing the same in SQL would be:

```
WHERE column_name1 IN (select ....) OR column_name2 IN (select ...)
```

The same query can be used directly in the active record:

```
where("column_name1 IN (select ...) OR column_name2 IN (select...)")
```

Avoiding duplication:

```
selected_values = select ...
where("column_name IN ? OR column_name2 in ?", selected_values, selected_values)
```

Comment: ```WHERE (column_name1, column_name1) IN (SELECT ....) ``` is valid, it's the same as doing an inner join by using them two columns. I've added an answer with my solution

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to use an inner join to gain the same functionality. Here is my solution.

```
  select(:column1, 'Count(1)').
  joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery.to_sql}) AS table2 ON   
  table1.column1=table2.column1
  AND table1.column2=table2.column2")
```